# Syntax Highlighting for Eclipse similar to Solarize

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, syntax-highlighting

Trying to add syntax highliting to Flash Builder withoutn having to do it from scratch.
Does anyone know of a eclipse plugin that supports custom syntax highliting 'presets'?
Trying to achieve something similar to solarized
http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](http://va.lent.in/blog/2011/04/07/more-on-flash-builder-color-themes/).